# Minus is not showing correctly in an eps file on Overleaf. But when I use a eps visualizer, the sign appears accurately

Tags: overleaf, eps, epslatex

Minus signs are not being displayed correctly, instead I get rectangles as you can see in the following image:
[image: Wrong imsge on Overleaf]

But when I use an eps visualizer I get the correct signs.

Here is the code on Overleaf I´m using:

```
\begin{figure}[thb]
    \centering
        \centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{torque_line_1cycle.eps}}
        \label{Tauns}
    \caption{Motion of the end-effector along a vertical line with null space displacements}
\end{figure}
```

And here the packages and format stuff:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage[implicit=false]{hyperref}

\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
% to typeset URLs, URIs, and DOIs
%\usepackage{url}
%\def\UrlFont{\rmfamily}
%\pdfminorversion=4


\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
    \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
    \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
    {\hfill \footnotesize XXX-X-XXXX-XXXX-X/XX/\$XX.XX \copyright 2022 IEEE\hfill}
}
\makeatother
```

You can get the file here:
https://espolec-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/jjpatino_espol_edu_ec/EbEjuvJ9gIZIuiutoWhwy8ABVAc9QdikV9ZahW_5eldejA?e=CxuKzm

Comment: We cannot test your code without the eps file. Are the fonts/font information embedded in the eps? If not, it could be that you have the needed font available locally, but Overleaf doesn't have it on the server. Do the other characters look the same?

Comment: @frabjous you can get the file now, I´ve shared a link

Comment: Thanks. I used inkscape to convert the eps to a small pdf with fonts embedded (though they may not be the ones you intended), which you can try substituting for the eps: [torque_line_1cycle.pdf](https://umass-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/klement_umass_edu/EXPbc5IeS2BLoa1Akb25l7kBymJCAvLKJYC4uNz204WDjA?e=XpUuFe). Let us know if that works. If it does, but you needed your original font, you may need to go back to whatever you used to make the eps and make sure you export it to a format with the fonts embedded.

Comment: Although looking at your screenshot, I think there may be other things missing from my conversion, but I don't know what they're supposed to be. Tau's, I guess?

Comment: Anyway, it seems to me there's something weird with the text/fonts in the eps; however I import it, and whatever software, either the minuses are missing, or the τ's are. I'm having trouble getting both. Incompatible font encodings perhaps. Where did you get it, or how did you make it?

Comment: I made it with Python in a Colab notebook. But when I display the image in a eps viewer, I get everything correctly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Colab notebook, but as I mentioned, this may require a particular collection of fonts you may have available in one place and not another. Try either exporting it to pdf (if it allows you), or even printing to pdf via a virtual printer from your eps viewer in a way that embeds the local fonts before uploading to Overleaf. In any case, I'm fairly sure the issue is with the eps, not your LaTeX code (or Overleaf).

Comment: the minus has a rather curious definition in the eps, it is not a proper glyph and that seems to break when converting to pdf.